# When to use ajax cache

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, struts2-jquery-plugin

Please consider below sample with struts 2 jquery plugin, ( but this could be happen with jquery)

In struts 2 jquery plugin set head tag to cache ajax calls:

```
ajaxcache="true"
```

The html head is ( do not cache any thing):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="No-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

There is also an interceptor which set resonse header as below:

```
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
            "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

Consider a sample test.jsp file with single js in it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/grid.js"></script>
```

The first time the test.jsp is loaded the `grid.js` is loaded and cached by browser, changing the `grid.js` will not cause the browser to get updated `grid.js` file any more !!

Of course I can fix this issue by setting `ajaxcache="false"`

My question is, if the `grid.js` is loaded only once and the client do not get newly updated js anymore, then what is the use of ajax caching ?!

Can you suggest a real case which you do not need to update any resource on the client, so client can catch a resource for a long time?!

Or we can use ajax caching in other ways ?!